# Await for event to fire until continuing the code

Tags: javascript, events, async-await, discord.js

I'm back again, again. I had a question about a Discord.js problem I've had. So, I'd like to check if a user joined a voiceChannel when the same user used a command. Then when he did join a voice-channel, I'd like to stop that listener on listening to that event.

Ok so, I have this little command set that checks whether the user is in a voice channel or not.

```js
if (!message.member.voiceChannel) {
    // Request to join voiceChannel.
}
```

After that, I have a message sent that says "Please join a voice channel" or whatever, not important. What is important, however, is the event I'd like to listen to, which is something along the lines of `voiceStateUpdate`. I'd like to await until that event fired (so when the user joined a voice channel), then execute the rest of the code after that.

```js
await Client.on("voiceStateUpdate", function (Old, member) {
    // Do stuff, event got fired.
});
```

Lastly, I'd like to know whether this is correctly possible or not. Awaiting​ for somebody to join a channel, then carrying on with the rest.

Thank you.
~Q

Comment: await awaits a promise, not a callback

Comment: Already knew that. Is there another possible way to handle this, listening to an event for only this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As bambam mentioned in his comment, you can't await a callback... In fact, that's the whole point of a callback - to keep the main thread free/running while a large action is completed.

I don't know the intricacies of the Discord library, so there might be a promise-version of the `Client.on(voiceStatusUpdate)` function... but just from a vanilla JS perspective, you could wrap your existing code in a promise, and `await` the completion of the promise:

```
await new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    Client.on("voiceStateUpdate", function (Old, member) {
        // Do stuff, event got fired.
        // After you've finished doing your stuff here, tell the promise you're finished.
        // Then, since the promise has "resolved", the code will continue past the "await"d line
        resolve()
    });
})
```

**Note that you'll have to mark your parent function with the `async` keyword in order to use `await` inside of it... but if you're messing with async/await, I imagine you're probably already familiar with that requirement.*

Comment: Ah! I didn't think of using promises and such. Thank you for the mind-breaking idea, haha.

Comment: @QSmally Awesome, glad it was useful! If my answer was helpful, please click the outlined checkmark to the left of the answer. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question will be marked as "having an accepted answer". It helps anyone searching for similar topics in the future, and gives me credit for the effort I put in. :) Thanks!

Comment: Great, thanks for letting me know. I'm pretty new here. I guess I can help people too around here, seems like it.